# Complete Statistic for a family with finite r-th moment

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, nonparametric, complete-statistics

Consider the family of all continuous distributions with finite $r$-th moment (where $r \geq 1$ is a given integer). We denote this family as, $$\mathscr{P}_r=\left\{f:f \ \text{is a pdf and} \int|x|^rf(x)\,dx<\infty\right\}.$$ Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ is a random sample from this family. Find a complete statistic for this family.
$$$$My attempt is as follows : Consider a family of distributions $$\mathscr{P'}=\{N(\mu, 1):\mu \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$ We know that $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\bar{X}$ is complete for $\mathscr{P}$ and as all the moments of a normal distribution are finite so $\mathscr{P'} \subset \mathscr{P}_r$. Now we show that $\mathscr{P'}$ dominates $\mathscr{P}_r$. We first show that if $g$ is a density function of $N(\mu, 1)$ for some $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, then $$\int_Ag(x)\,dx=0 \Longleftrightarrow m(A)=0$$ where $m(A)$ is the Lebesgue measure of the set $A$. Now if $m(A)=0$ the clearly the integral is zero as a density function is always bounded. Now suppose that the integral is $0$ for some set $A$ with positive measure. WLOG assume that $A$ is bounded .So $m(A)>0$, then the inner measure of $A$ is also positive. By the definition of the inner measure there exists a closed bounded subset of $A$ say $E$ such that $m(E)>0$. Now as $E$ is closed and bounded so it is compact and as $g$ is a continuous function so there exists a $x_0 \in E$ such that $g(x) \geq g(x_0)>0$ for all $x \in E$. Then we have $$\int_Ag(x)\,dx \geq \int_Eg(x)\,dx \geq \int_Eg(x_0)\,dx =g(x_0)m(E)>0$$ which is a contradiction. So $m(A)=0$. So we have shown that for any $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, if $g$ is a density function of $N(\mu, 1)$ whose integral on a set $A$ is zero then $m(A)=0$ for any set $A$. So for any set $A$ such that integral of $g$ on $A$ is $0$, then $m(A)=0$ for any $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and so for any $f \in \mathscr{P}_r$ , integral of $f$ on $A$ is zero as $f$ is a density function and so is bounded. So $\mathscr{P}'$ dominates $\mathscr{P}_r$ and so $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\bar{X}$ is complete for $\mathscr{P}_r$ also.

$$$$Is my proof correct?